# how to execute data.frame in tree ring series

Tags: r

How to execute a data.frame containing 46 tree-ring series in columns and 307 years in rows?

[image: image attached]

Comment: Does "executing a dataframe" mean "removing with extreme predjudice"?

Comment: Do not post your data as an image, please learn how to give a  [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) .